# wordpress - Issue With custom post types and permalinks

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with Custom Post Types for the first time and running into a vexing problem:

I can add and query the post types, but they always show up as:

domain.com/post-type-name/post-title

I have no rewrite in place, and my permalink structure is set to %postname% only, and I am flushing the rules immediately following adding the post type.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be helpful to solve the problem:
http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you!  That link also helped me understand inserting custom re-write rules better, so double thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may try two things

1. Just visit your `Permalink Settings` from the `settings` menu and save the page again.

or you may try

```
register_post_type('post-type-name', array(
    //...
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'','with_front'=>false),
    //...
));
```

Comment: Yes I tried this and it puts the name of the post type in its place.  Kind of strange!